# WP8.1 Inputpane (Keyboard) pushes/shifts cordovaView/Html content

Tags: javascript, c#, html, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I encountered a very strange behaviour in my ionic/cordova app on the windows phone 8.1 platform, where i implemented an instant messenger.  I teared my whole application down to a simple cordova (starter) application to eliminate potential side effects with other app related code like other css classes for example. But the issue still remains...

---

***The issue***

My app contains an html input element at the bottom of the page, where the user can enter a text for text-messaging. Whenever this input gets focused, the keyboard (inputpane) appears. But after the first focussing (by clicking the 2nd++ time), the input shifts up **too far** or gets pushed away by the keyboard. These are the screen captures:

1. Everything is fine on first focus:

[image]

2. Hiding the Keyboard by pressing "back button" and refocussing the input leads into that:

[image]

It seems like the **whole application gets pushed away** by the keyboard out of the screen, since the header bar disappers as well. After tapping on the screen, the view renders correctly (Picture 1), but the usability remains still like a mess. I only figured out, that the space below the input element belongs to the `<body>` of the DOM.

---

***What i did so far***

I started with creating a plain cordova app to narrow down all potential side effects and error sources ([Source code on my Github](https://github.com/beat-at-hartwig/wpBug)). This was my procedure:

1. Created a new cordova application with cordova 5.1.1
2. `cordova platform add wp8` & `cordova build wp8`
3. Opened the wp8 project file with Visual Studio 2013 and upgraded to a windows phone silverlight 8.1 application (see picture below), because this is a requirement by our app

[image]

4. And started to copy the essential html/css/js code to reproduce the issue in the plain application with:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bottom">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.bottom {
  position : absolute;
  right    : 0;
  left     : 0;
  bottom   : 0;
}

input {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

***Result***

First of all, I thought the problem disappeared. But after some trying I encountered the same behaviour again. It happens quite rarely but still (only once in ~30 times). For me this was the evidence, that for example ionic is not responsible for this issue (see picture below):

[image]

It already took days and hours to investigate this behaviour and to try all potential solutions i have found in the world wide web until today. These are for example:

- [Altering the CordovaView Margin in the MainPage.xaml](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6906)
- [Resizing the app natively on keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202171/resize-winrt-page-when-on-on-screen-keyboard-showing)
- [Adding event listener to my javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820088/how-to-prevent-keyboard-push-up-webview-at-ios-app-using-phonegap)

Additionally i installed [WEINRE](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) to debug my web related code on the windows phone 8.1 device (Nokia Lumia 930) with minor success. The same issue also appears in a simulator. I can only image, that upgrading to a silverlight 8.1 app is the essential breaking changer.

Comment: I added the source code of the blank cordova application to my github account [LINK](https://github.com/beat-at-hartwig/wpBug)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false) ? In order to enable the native scrolling.
I have the exact same issue.

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
 
  // Or for only a single platform, use
  // if( ionic.Platform.isAndroid() ) {
    // $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
  // }
}
```

Comment: I actually changed my platform target to `windows` instead of `wp8`. That helped. I am using `$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling( true );` by the way and it is working. Seems like you have a different problem…